# Adding ActionListeners to buttons in Java

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to understand how I can print out info after clicking the button. I have tried several things but I am learning on my own. I am currently on knowing the different Listeners so help me on the adding the button Listener.

I wanted when a combobox is selected it prints out info and shows some details. I have a button but I want once the info in the combobox is selected it prints out info.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class ItemCheck extends JFrame{

    JComboBox PainandFeverReliever;
    JButton button1;
    JLabel lable;

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ItemCheck();
    }

    public ItemCheck(){
        this.setSize(400,400);

        this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        this.setTitle("Medicine Stock");

        JPanel thePanel = new JPanel();
        JLabel label = new JLabel (" Medicine");
        label.setToolTipText("This Shows you how many medicine you have left in the store.");
        thePanel.add(label);

        String[] shows = {"","Cetaminophen" , "ephedrine","menthol"};

        PainandFeverReliever = new JComboBox(shows);
        PainandFeverReliever.addItem("Pushing Daisies");

        thePanel.add(PainandFeverReliever);

        button1 = new JButton("Results");

        ListenForButton lForButton = new ListenForButton();

        button1.addActionListener(lForButton);
        thePanel.add(button1);

        this.add(thePanel);

        this.setVisible(true);

        PainandFeverReliever.insertItemAt("diphenhydramine", 1);

        PainandFeverReliever.setMaximumRowCount(20);
    }

    private void setForeground(int hsBtoRGB) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    private class ListenForButton implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            if(e.getSource() == button1){
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Android tag removed -- what does this question have to do with Android programming?

Comment: ... and what's your question? About adding an ActionListener to a JButton? But you're already doing that.

Comment: You just add your code in the actionPerformed() method.

Comment: @Nikola he doesn't have access to button1.

Comment: Add an ActionListener to the JComboBox

Comment: Try the [Combo Box tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/combobox.html) from Oracle.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I think you need to introduce a string – remember you can call it whatever you want to, then after that you will need to add it to your button function and then that will print out the info you want.I am doing this since i understand you want to view info from a JComboBox and this is how it should be done.

call the string info.

try adding this info in your button and maybe you can learn afew from it. also i recommend you read more about JOptionPane.

```
 String info;
        PainandFeverReliever.setEditable(true);       
 info = "Item : " + PainandFeverReliever.getItemAt(0) + "\n";
 info  += "Count; " + PainandFeverReliever.getItemCount() + "\n";
 info += "Selected ID: " + PainandFeverReliever.getSelectedIndex() + "\n";
 info += "Selected : " + PainandFeverReliever.getSelectedItem() + "\n";
 info += "Combo Box Editable: " + PainandFeverReliever.isEditable() + "\n";
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(ItemCheck.this, info, "Information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
info = "";
```

Comment: I see. so where do i put the string info? do i make it a global variable?

Comment: (I wanted when a combobox is selected it prints out info and shows some details) trying to answer in regards to this. Thats what i understand the person needs or am i wrong?

Comment: Well, his combo box is part of the GUI, and you're showing a dialog box. Those are not the same things.

Comment: Realskeptic i am new in java and i want when i click my button some info to be printed out.. once any of my string (combobox info) is selected.. i dont know am clear like ifselected.. to show true and print out. syombua i want to try the code now and hopefly i will also steal one or two from there. thank you all. i will need to learn english phew!

Comment: now this code has introduced me to what can be done with the jcombobox like getting the iteam at, selected index and selected item, not bad.

Comment: @RealSkeptic i will look at more tutorials too. Thank you all.

Comment: I just wanted to demonstrate what i understood in your question. Glad to see you liked it.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to know how to add a listener to a combo box. You can do that in a way similar to the way you can use for a button. For the `PainandFeverReliever` combo box, you could add this code after you've created it (assuming you are using Java 8 or newer):

```
PainandFeverReliever.addActionListener(
        actionEvent -> System.out.println("Selected medicine: "
                                + PainandFeverReliever.getSelectedItem())
);
```

Comment: Ts is a general nit pick, but as a Java developer for 15 years, I really find this shortcut really hard to read, it des the actual contract of the method and the parameters. If I didn't know better, I'd be asking, what is "e" and where did it come from and why do I need. For a new developer who doesn't yet understand the relationship between the component and the listener, I'd say it would be impossible for them to understand, but that's just me ;)

Comment: I used a terrible name in this example, since `e` is usually used for exceptions and doesn't clarify what it is (replaced it with `actionEvent` now). And yes, the new lambda syntax can be a bit cryptic, but it was introduced in Java 8 to be able to reduce the amount of boiler plate code. I have to get used to it myself, but I'm trying to see if it works in certain situations; it might be easier for me, since I'm only a Java developer for 14 years... ;-)

Comment: I was trying to read some code the other week which was full of lambda expressions and I got to the point where I just had no idea what the hell it was talking about, but that's just me :P